# out of heap space memory error

Tags: java, netbeans, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run the coreNLP package with the following program

```
package corenlp;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 *
 * @author Karthi
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO code application liogic here
        String str="-cp stanford-corenlp-2010-11-12.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-2010-11-06.jar:xom-1.2.6.jar:jgrapht-0.7.3.jar -Xms3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP [ -props <Main> ] -file <input.txt>";
        args=str.split(" ");
        StanfordCoreNLP scn=new StanfordCoreNLP();
        scn.main(args);
    }

}
```

I am not sure if the code itself is correct, but am getting the following error

```
    Searching for resource: StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Searching for resource: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Loading POS Model [edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/wsj3t0-18-left3words/left3words-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger] ... Loading default properties from trained tagger edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/wsj3t0-18-left3words/left3words-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/wsj3t0-18-left3words/left3words-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:704)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:649)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:268)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:228)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:57)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:44)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:441)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:434)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:62)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:309)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:347)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:337)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:329)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:319)
        at corenlp.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Java Result: 1
```

I tried giving these values in VM options in netbeans, but for each value i am getting error

-Xms3g

```
run:
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible initial and maximum heap sizes specified
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

-Xmx3g

```
run:
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

-Xms3g -Xmx4g

```
run:
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Please go ahead and accept some of your previous questions..

Comment: Thanks i have accepted the answers in my previous questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which OS are you running this on? Is it a 64 bit system? If not, then you are pretty much restricted when it comes to how much heap you can allocate to a single Java process. Try running with `-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M` and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Yes it is 64 bit system and stanford websiite said it needs atleast 3gb heap space

Comment: it started running.. but after 5 min it reported out of memory error again

Comment: @karthi: Strange; if it is a 64 bit VM on a 64 bit OS, it shouldn't be a problem. `3G` is nothing. We run around 8 VM's each having around `4096M` on our production servers. Try removing the existing parameters and using `-Xms4096M -Xmx4096M`.

Comment: yes.. that is the problem.. the system came with pre installed 32bit jvm.. now downloaded 64 bit and installed, hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

try with the runtime parameters

`java -cp -XX:+AggressiveHeap  -jar jarfile`

or

`java -cp... -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+UseLargePages -jar jarfile`

Comment: where should i give these parameters?.. am new to these heapspace options